# Talend studio : how to add libraries available to all jobs or routes?

Tags: java, editor, talend

In Talend Studio (open ESB version 6.3), in the java bean editor, some libraries are available without having to put a cConfig in the route, for instance java.utils.*, org.apache.log4j etc..
[image]
Strangely, this list of available imports becomes really longer after we have compiled/run any route, but it still does not contain some librairies we need.

How can we retrieve the list of all the libraries available there (without guessing the first part for autocompletion), and how can we add some others ?

We will have hundreds of route and for maintenance we prfer not to add a cConfig in all the routes but call a repository bean that will do all that we need.

More precisely, we need to send emails, but "javax.mail" is not found in the java bean editor, though we can see javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar file in Studio/plugins. "org.apache.commons.mail" is not found too.

Thanks
Loko

Answer (score 1):

I finally found by myself : right click on the bean in the Repository view and select "Edit bean libraries"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JavaMail is present in the Studio installation but it is for use with the *cMail* component so if you need to send mail in a route then you should use that component and not code it. In a job, you should use a *tSendMail* component.

Comment: I know the tSendMail and cMail components, but this is not what we need, we want to send emails in a java bean as said in my first message